# Draw Multiple Canvas on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw multiple canvas on a single page, something like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas_1" width="71" height="80"></canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_2" width="71" height="80"></canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_3" width="71" height="80"></canvas>
```

And my script to draw canvas at id "myCanvas_1" is:

```
<script>

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');

      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 75;
      var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      var endAngle = 0.6 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      context.lineWidth = 150;

      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();


    </script>
```

How can I "loop" this script to draw canvas also on id "myCanvas_2", id "myCanvas_3" etc...?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a  a js for,

for example :

```
for(i = 1 ; i<4 ; i++){

 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas_'+i);
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 0.6 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineWidth = 150;

  // line color
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to each canvas as `class="canvasscript"`

```
<canvas id="myCanvas_1" width="71" height="80" class="canvasscript"></canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_2" width="71" height="80" class="canvasscript"></canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas_3" width="71" height="80" class="canvasscript"></canvas>
```

**In Script**

`var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName(canvasscript);`

Hope It helps.